# Print only Image without whole HTML page

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to print only the image in a HTML page.

I used

```
function printImg(){        
    var URL = "image.png";
    var W = window.open(URL);
    W.window.print();
}
```

But executing the code, whole page prints rather the image. Are there any method to print only the image? Pls guide me.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: How did you call this function?

Comment: <input type="submit" value="Print" name="printImg" onClick="printImg()">

Comment: Try to add `return false;` at the end of function in this case.

Comment: @Isuru Senanayake: See my answer below with a demo.

Comment: @IsuruSenanayake, This can't be done. You can't modify browser settings (i.e. printer settings) from JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I thought of convert my result to PDF format and print using [FPDF Library](http://fpdf.org/)

Answer (score 1):

create one print.css that hide all other unwanted divs except the image

Comment: could you pls give me a example link.

Comment: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/05/05/how-to-create-a-simple-print-css-for-your-site/
you can hide all elements in your page that you dont want it to appear during printing

Comment: Keep in mind that this approach could make it difficult for people to print off the whole page if they want the rest of it - not just the image.

Comment: yes, but in this case, this is the simplest trick i can think of.
and in fact, the file can be manipulated easily

Comment: @Isuru Senanayake: See my [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12347310/1516616) below with a demo.

Answer (score 1):

If you heard about [**CSS Media types**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) then you can achieve your desired task with this technique.

Example:

Define Media Type Print and then add a css class`.noprint` with a css rule `display:none;` in your css file like given below:

```
@media print {
   .noprint{ display: none }
}
```

And then apply this class on the elements you don't want to print.

[**SEE AN EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/3Rjjx/)

Hope this will help you a lot.

Comment: Yep, I got the point. But, see the image  I have uploaded. You will see what actually I want to do

Comment: i dont think that can be removed. someone pls correct me if im wrong

Comment: @s3polz It is a browser setting, not sure if you can javascript it out, though I do recall a good few questions about it here that might give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
W.print();
```

instead of

```
W.window.print();
```

`W.window` makes reference to the parent's window of the pop-up.

Besides this you may consider using an empty page with a `window.print` triggered on load, instead of your current method which is not waiting for the image to be ready.

### == EDIT ==

This can't be done. You can't modify browser settings (i.e. printer settings) from JavaScript

Answer (score -1):

You can create an image element then append it to the DOM.

```
function printImg() {
    var img = document.createElement( "img" );
    img.src = "image.png";
    document.body.appendChild( img );
}
```